# How can I test the changes I make to my app without reinstalling it every time?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, reinstall

I'm hoping this isn't some super rookie question, but I find it wholly impractical to have to reinstall the application on my device every time I run it. Maybe I'm just being impatient but I feel that I am losing a huge accumulation of time to reinstalls.

I did look into "Debugging mode" on Eclipse after I was clued that my solution may be there, but to no avail. Android forum sites were also not very helpful, so if you post a link, please make sure it offers a direct explanation. From a distressed developer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- It reinstall your app because every time you change the code (Eclipe, Android studio, etc.) have to complile this new code.
- I think fastes way is to use your own android phone/device as AVD (but AVD is slow), connect it via usb and turn on usb debugging.

Comment: that's not what I was asking, but are you saying there is NO other way to load my new code onto my phone?

Answer (score 1):

A new apk must be built each time you want to test your changes but it's actually quite fast and easy to deploy a new apk on a phone automatically with ADB when pressing the "run" or "debug" button in Eclipse. Also, Eclipse uses incremental compilation which speeds up the process of generating the new apk before deployment. On my machine it takes 5-10 seconds between the button press and the new apk starting on the phone.

You need to have your phone connected with a USB cable and enable USB debugging on the phone to use ADB.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in the world of unit test framework... just use for example [robolectric](http://robolectric.org) 
Running tests on an Android emulator or device is slow! Building, deploying, and launching the app often takes a minute or more. so run your Android tests directly from inside your IDE and check for results...

Comment: Sounds intriguing, please explain how it works because I went to the website, and maybe I AM too rookie, but I found it too esoteric.

Comment: not at all, it s easy to use .... follow this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Robolectric/article.html)